# QPixmap.fromImage(QImage) returns null when converting QImage to Qpixmap

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt, qpixmap

I am trying to display an image published as ROS topic, in my GUI written in PYQT4. I am taking my ROS Image messages and converting it into a opencv image using cv_bridge. I then convert the opencv image into Qimage which is then converted into QPixmap to display it with a QLabel. The code snippet is

```
def CallbackFrntCamImg(self,msg):
        self.StatusFrntCam = True
        FrntCamImg = self.CVBridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(msg, desired_encoding="passthrough")
        cv2.imwrite("testimg.jpg",FrntCamImg)
        FrntCamImg = cv2.cvtColor(FrntCamImg,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        height,width,channel = FrntCamImg.shape
        frntcamimg = QImage(FrntCamImg,width,height,channel*width,QImage.Format_RGB888)
        frntcamimg.save("TestImage.png")
        self.frntcamqimg = QPixmap.fromImage(frntcamimg,Qt.AutoColor)
        if self.frntcamqimg.isNull():
            print "PixMap Image is NULL"
```

It looks like the CV image is being converted into QImage successfully, but the QPixmap that I generate from the QImage is Null.

I know that ROS Image -> CV Image and CV Image -> QImage works, because I am able to save the images successfully and view it.

I tried different flags, but makes no difference. I am not sure what I am missing. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks